# Is there a word for making two things indistinguishable?

Tags: single-word-requests

Suppose we have two objects which are different and can be distinguished. Is there a word for the operation of making them indistinguishable, or for the act of declaring that it is not allowed to distinguish them, or for the rule that it is not allowed to distinguish them?

Comment: This sounds like three separate questions with differing answers.  Can you add some context --provide the desired usage?

Comment: Are you looking for a synonym of "making a perfect copy" or are you expecting some different connotation?

Comment: It's a bit difficult to provide context, because I need this word to describe a concept in mathematics, specifically homotopy type theory. To understand the context one would have to be familiar with that field. Some existing suggestions are nondiscrimination rule (but this doesn't work well for turning it into a verb "to nondiscriminate two objects"), and identify/identification ("we identify x with y", but this has other connotations: "identification rule" sounds like a passport check), or equalize (not the right meaning; inability to distinguish two things doesn't mean that they are equal).

Comment: I'm not looking for "making a perfect copy". There are two existing objects. I guess the closest everyday situation is that by law you are not allowed to discriminate/distinguish between people with different skin color.

Comment: You are then refering to **equality of treatment**. According to this view, similarly situated people should be treated equally. *For instance, all people who commit the same crime under the same circumstances should be punished in the same way; differences in treatment should arise only from differences in the circumstances surrounding the crime*.

Comment: Yes, that is right. Is there a single word for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you are actually making them alike, you could describe this as **conforming** one to the other or conforming them to each other.

> to make similar in form, nature, or character.
>   to bring into agreement, correspondence, or harmony.
>   - [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/conforming)

I'm not aware of a specific term for simply declaring them to be identical.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the verbs **counterfeit** or **forge** or the corresponding nouns, i.e.  *counterfeiting* or *forgery* ?

> From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counterfeit): *To counterfeit means to imitate something.
>   Counterfeit products are fake replicas of the real product.
>   Counterfeit products are often produced with the intent to take
>   advantage of the superior value of the imitated product. The word
>   counterfeit frequently describes both the forgeries of currency and
>   documents, as well as the imitations of clothing, handbags, shoes,
>   pharmaceuticals, aviation and automobile parts, watches, electronics
>   (both parts and finished products), software, works of art, toys,
>   movies. Counterfeit products tend to have fake company logos and brands.*

.

> *To forge is to produce something not genuine, for example to forge a  document or a signature*.

Answer (score 0):

As to the first part of the question, Chris Sunami's suggestion of *conforming* seems appropriate.

As to the latter part, the legal concept of *deeming equivalent* seems to apply. *Deem* means

> To hold; consider; adjudge; believe; condemn; determine; treat as if; construe.

*West's Encyclopedia of American Law* (found at [thefreedictionary.com](http://legal-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/deem))

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question...

> Is there a word for the operation of making them indistinguishable[?]

...you could say to *become a clone of*.

#### clone

> a person or thing that duplicates, imitates, or closely resembles another in appearance, function, performance, or style.

~ [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/clone)